# Best practice for dynamically removing a Spring ApplicationListener?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to register and unregister Spring ApplicationListeners dynamically at run-time and not in a Spring config file.

If I can't remove them dynamically, I'll have a memory leak.

Here's my best guess:

I could call `AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster().add/removeApplicationListener()`.

Is that the recommended method?

Does anyone remove listeners dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works.  This is especially useful for prototype beans that implement ApplicationListener and are created/destroyed frequently.  If you don't unregister them, you'll end up with a memory leak.

```
ApplicationEventMulticaster aem = context.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.APPLICATION_EVENT_MULTICASTER_BEAN_NAME, ApplicationEventMulticaster.class);

aem.removeApplicationListener(appListener);
```

Comment: Along with the above two lines, i also had to add:  `BeanDefinitionRegistry factory = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

  ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) factory).destroySingleton("validationEventListener");`  For destroying and removing the listener from the context.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using 2 methods in [`AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.html).

1. [`removeApplicationListenerBean(String listenerBeanName)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.html#removeApplicationListenerBean-java.lang.String-)
2. [`removeApplicationListener(ApplicationListener<?> listener)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.html#removeApplicationListener-org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener-)

Ex:

```
//Listener class.
@Component
public class CustomEventListener implements ApplicationListener <CustomEvent>{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomEvent event) {
      //Your logic goes here
    }
}
```

```
//Event Publisher class
@Component
public class CustomEventListener {
    
    @Autowired
    private SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomEventListener listener;
    
    public void doStuffAndPublishAnEvent(CustomEvent customEvent) {
        multicaster.removeApplicationListener(listener);
        multicaster.removeApplicationListenerBean(listener.getClass().getSimpleName());
        multicaster.multicastEvent(customEvent);
}
```

Note: [`SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.html)  extends `AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method that you have recommended is good. You can also make your listener to remove itself using the same or similar technique.

However I'd ask myself other question: why do I have memory leak and is there a way to fix it without removing the listener?

Comment: The memory leak occurs because I have obsolete listeners on the bus taking up time (they still get called) and space.

Comment: You should wrap the add-remove sequence in a try-finally block