# Dynamically remove a @EventListener in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to remove or add Spring ApplicationListeners dynamically in my (test) code.

Using Spring's `ApplicationEventMulticaster` as outlined in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930254/best-practice-for-dynamically-removing-a-spring-applicationlistener) would work for me,
however the specific `ApplicationListener` I'm interested in is implemented using an `@EventListener` annotated method, which results in an `ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter`-Object at runtime.

How can I get hold of the name of this bean, so that I can remove the bean with the `ApplicationEventMulticaster`?

```
eventMulticaster.removeApplicationListenerBean("NAME_OF_APPLICATION_METHOD_ADAPTER_BEAN")
```

Comment: After a debugging session it seems like this is not possible atm. Filed an issue with Spring: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26638

Comment: Why don't you want to use the conditionals mechanism? I mean define a listener with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, set it "true" by default (production), and set it to false from the test... The bean with the listener won't load... If you want to add something for the test - define a special configuration...

Comment: I was experimenting with the `condition` property on `@EventListener` and this would work. However, that would require extra code in the production code base just for testing purposes. See my answer: Extending `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` avoids that and is thus a little bit less intrusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Spring 5.3.5 `@EventListener` has an `id` property, which you can then use to remove the listener programmatically:

```
eventMulticaster.removeApplicationListeners(l -> l instanceof SmartApplicationListener &&
    ((SmartApplicationListener) l).getListenerId().startsWith("myrootpackage.mymodule"))
```

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26638

Answer (score 0):

The public API from Spring unfortunately only supports adding or removing programmatically defined `ApplicationListener`s.

I was able to solve my problem, though, by subclassing Spring's `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` and some reflection vodoo.

It's not ideal, but if somebody else has a similar problem, this is how my configurable multicaster looks like:

```
package at.codemonkey.event;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Optional.empty;
import static org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findField;
import static org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible;

public class FilteringApplicationEventMulticaster extends SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster {

  private final Field beanNameField;
  private final Set<String> disabledListeners = new HashSet<>();

  FilteringApplicationEventMulticaster() {
    beanNameField = findField(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.class, "beanName");
    assert beanNameField != null;
    makeAccessible(beanNameField);
  }

  @Override
  protected void invokeListener(@NonNull ApplicationListener<?> listener, @NonNull ApplicationEvent event) {
    if (!filter(listener)) {
      super.invokeListener(listener, event);
    }
  }

  private boolean filter(ApplicationListener<?> listener) {
    return getBeanName(listener).filter(disabledListeners::contains).isPresent();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
  private Optional<String> getBeanName(ApplicationListener<?> listener) {
    return (listener instanceof ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter) ? Optional.of((String) ReflectionUtils.getField(beanNameField, listener)) : empty();
  }

  public void enable(String... listenerBeans) {
    disabledListeners.removeAll(List.of(listenerBeans));
  }

  public void disable(String... listenerBeans) {
    disabledListeners.addAll(List.of(listenerBeans));
  }

}
```

Configuring the Multicaster in a SpringBoot application is fairly straightforward:

```
package at.codemonkey.event;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootConfiguration
class ApplicationEventConfiguration {

  @Bean
  FilteringApplicationEventMulticaster applicationEventMulticaster() {
    return new FilteringApplicationEventMulticaster();
  }

}
```

You can now enable/disable listeners dynamically by using the name of the bean, where the `@EventListener` is defined.

Suppose, you have the following listener:

```
@Component
class MyEventListener {

  @EventListener
  public void handle(MyEvent event) { ... } 

}
```

You can now disable or enable this listener (in a test case for example) by injecting the `FilteringApplicationEventMulticaster`:

```
eventMulticaster.enable("myEventListener");
eventMulticaster.disable("myEventListener");
```

The current implementation will disable all `@EventListeners` of the bean, which is fine for me. It should be, however, easy to extend the existing solution if you need more fine grained control.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some more ways of disabling listeners described here (https://dzone.com/articles/spring-application-listeners-review-and-ways-to-di).

**1. Using org.springframework.context.event.EventListener@#condition**

For example,

```
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class TestListener {

    @EventListener(condition = "@environment.getProperty('listeners.enabled')")
    void handle(final ContextRefreshedEvent e) {
        System.out.println("@EventListener works!");
    }
}
```

**2. Using org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty**

This works for both listeners created using org.springframework.context.event.EventListener annotation and beans that implement  org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener or org.springframework.context.event.SmartApplicationListener. For example,

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "listeners.enabled", havingValue = "true")
class TestApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ApplicationListener works");
    }
}
```

However, if you have several methods marked with @EventListener annotation, you will disable all of them.

**3. Using org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle Bean**

The idea is to register a bean that implements org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle interface and disables listeners when starting. As soon as lifecycle beans are initialized and started before publishing org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent event, this approach will be enough in many cases. It works for both listeners created using org.springframework.context.event.EventListener annotation and beans that implement  org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener or org.springframework.context.event.SmartApplicationListener as well.

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;
import org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationEventMulticaster;
import org.springframework.context.event.SmartApplicationListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull;

public class DisableEventListenersBean implements SmartLifecycle {
    private final Set<String> ids;
    private final Set<String> names;
    private final Set<Class<?>> types;
    private final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster;

    public DisableEventListenersBean(
            final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster,
            final String... ids
    ) {
        this.multicaster = multicaster;
        this.types = Collections.emptySet();
        this.names = Collections.emptySet();
        this.ids = Arrays.stream(ids).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public DisableEventListenersBean(
            final ApplicationContext context,
            final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster,
            final Class<?>... types
    ) {
        this(
                Collections.emptySet(), Arrays.stream(types).collect(Collectors.toSet()), context, multicaster
        );
    }

    public DisableEventListenersBean(
            final Set<String> ids,
            final Set<Class<?>> types,
            final ApplicationContext context,
            final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster
    ) {
        this.multicaster = multicaster;
        this.ids = defaultIfNull(ids, Collections.emptySet());
        this.types = defaultIfNull(types, Collections.emptySet());
        this.names = types.stream().map(context::getBeanNamesForType).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        multicaster.removeApplicationListeners(
                listener -> {
                    final boolean toRemove;
                    if (listener instanceof SmartApplicationListener smart) {
                        toRemove = ids.contains(smart.getListenerId()) || shouldDisableForType(listener);
                    } else {
                        toRemove = shouldDisableForType(listener);
                    }
                    return toRemove;
                }
        );
        multicaster.removeApplicationListenerBeans(
                names::contains
        );
    }

    private boolean shouldDisableForType(final ApplicationListener<?> type) {
        final var actual = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(type);
        return types.contains(actual);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and configuration

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationEventMulticaster;

import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
class CustomApplicationEventConfig {

//    @Bean
//    SmartLifecycle disableEventListenersBean(final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster) {
//        return new DisableEventListenersBean(
//                multicaster,
//                "com.example.demo.events.app.TestListener.handle(org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent)"
//        );
//    }

//    @Bean
//    SmartLifecycle disableEventListenersBean(
//            final ApplicationContext context, final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster
//    ) {
//        return new DisableEventListenersBean(
//                context,
//                multicaster,
//                TestApplicationListener.class
//        );
//    }
    @Bean
    SmartLifecycle disableEventListenersBean(
            final ApplicationContext context, final ApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster
    ) {
        return new DisableEventListenersBean(
                Set.of(
                        "com.example.demo.events.app.TestListener.handle(org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent)"
                ),
                Set.of(
                       TestApplicationListener.class, TestSmartApplicationListener.class
                ),
                context,
                multicaster
        );
    }
}
```

java.lang.Class.forName(String) is used everywhere because com.example.demo.events.app.TestListener may have package-private access.

**4. Replacing default org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory bean**

Listeners created using org.springframework.context.event.EventListener annotation are processed by org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor. It creates instance of ApplicationListener<?> or SmartApplicationListener using org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory based on annotation parameters and adds it to multicaster. Spring itself has a default implementation of org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory. It is org.springframework.context.event.DefaultEventListenerFactory, that creates org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter instance, that implements SmartApplicationListener. The bean name for DefaultEventListenerFactory is AnnotationConfigUtils.EVENT_LISTENER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME.

So,

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DisableEventListenerFactory implements EventListenerFactory {
    private final Set<Class<?>> types;

    public DisableEventListenerFactory(final Class<?>... types) {
        this.types = Arrays.stream(types).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsMethod(final Method method) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener<?> createApplicationListener(
            final String name, final Class<?> type, final Method method
    ) {
        final ApplicationListener<?> listener;
        if (types.contains(ClassUtils.getUserClass(type))) {
            listener = event -> {};
        } else {
            listener = new ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter(name, type, method);
        }
        return listener;
    }
}
```

If you need to disable only some annotated methods within the same class, you can easily add method information, i.e., method name and parameter type.

And config

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConstructorArgumentValues;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class RegisterEventListenerFactoryProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        if (registry.containsBeanDefinition(AnnotationConfigUtils.EVENT_LISTENER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)) {
            registry.removeBeanDefinition(AnnotationConfigUtils.EVENT_LISTENER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME);
        }
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(
                AnnotationConfigUtils.EVENT_LISTENER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME,
                createDisableEventListenerFactoryBeanDefinition()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private RootBeanDefinition createDisableEventListenerFactoryBeanDefinition() {
        final var bd = new RootBeanDefinition();
        bd.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
        bd.setAutowireMode(AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE);
        bd.setBeanClass(DisableEventListenerFactory.class);
        final var constructorValues = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
        constructorValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(
                0,
                new Class<?>[] {
                        Class.forName("com.example.demo.events.app.TestListener")
                }
        );
        bd.setConstructorArgumentValues(constructorValues);
        return bd;
    }
}
```

or you can create bean as usual, but you should switch on spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding.

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory;

@Configuration
class CustomApplicationEventConfig {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean(AnnotationConfigUtils.EVENT_LISTENER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
    EventListenerFactory disableEventListenerFactory() {
        return new DisableEventListenerFactory(
                Class.forName("com.example.demo.events.app.TestListener")
        );
    }
}
```

and application.properties

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

However, using BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor is more safe. Actually spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding will not give any guarantees on which implementation will be used. Besides, overriding may work for other beans when you do not need it.

This approach works only for listeners created using org.springframework.context.event.EventListener annotation.

**5. Replacing Default org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationEventMulticaster bean**

It's enough only for listeners that are created without org.springframework.context.event.EventListener annotation.

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DisableApplicationEventMulticaster extends SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster {
    private final Set<Class<ApplicationListener<?>>> types;

    public DisableApplicationEventMulticaster(final Class<ApplicationListener<?>>... types) {
        this.types = Arrays.stream(types).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public DisableApplicationEventMulticaster(final BeanFactory factory, final Class<ApplicationListener<?>>... types) {
        super(factory);
        this.types = Arrays.stream(types).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    protected void invokeListener(final ApplicationListener<?> listener, final ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (!types.contains(AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(listener))) {
            super.invokeListener(listener, event);
        }
    }
}
```

and config

```
@Configuration
class CustomApplicationEventConfig {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean(AbstractApplicationContext.APPLICATION_EVENT_MULTICASTER_BEAN_NAME)
    ApplicationEventMulticaster disableApplicationEventMulticaster() {
        return new DisableApplicationEventMulticaster(
                (Class<ApplicationListener<?>>) Class.forName("com.example.demo.events.app.TestApplicationListener"),
                (Class<ApplicationListener<?>>) Class.forName("com.example.demo.events.app.TestSmartApplicationListener")
        );
    }
}
```

Spring Boot version 3.0.2 (Spring version 6.0.4).
Refer to https://dzone.com/articles/spring-application-listeners-review-and-ways-to-di for more details.

Comment: All your answers do not allow for dynamic (i.e., during runtime) starting and stopping of listeners. See my answer how to do this the Spring authoritative way.